# GWT cellTable - new row handler?

Tags: gwt, celltable

I want to change some fields every time my cellTable content changes (new row, row change). Is there any predefined event/handler for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if `addRangeChangeHandler` or `addRowCountChangeHandler` in [HasRows](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/HasRows.html) meet your needs.

If by "row change" you mean a change in selected row(s), you can use SelectionChangeHandler attached to a SelectionModel.

Otherwise, you can simply call whatever method you need when you add a row or update a data provider.

Comment: RowCountChangeHandler did the job. Cheers